# How to read RFC822 content as plain text?

Tags: lotus-domino

First thing to note...I have tried a simple doc.computewithform(false,false) and it did not resolve this.

I have an agent set to run after new mail arrives.    This agent will do different things depending on the email address it was sent to.   Several email addresses are pointed to this mail-in db.   So, in order for this to work, I need to read the 'sendto' field on the incoming email.   Sometimes this value is plain text, and that works fine.  Sometimes, depending on where the email was initiated, the sendto value is RFC822 text.    I am hoping to find a way to convert this or extract from it the plain text representation of the sendto address.

I have a local memo form in this database that I could add an @Formula language function to, should one exist (so I could look there after the computewithform call).

If anyone has any ideas, I would be grateful for your input.

- Matt

Comment: Use [NotesName- Class](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_NOTESNAME_CLASS.html) and its Addr821* and Addr822*- Methods... Please in the future add your example code as otherwise this will be closed as "Needs Details or Clarity" or "Add Debugging Details".

Answer (score 0):

@Name([Abbreviate];SendTo) will extract the text from a field of RFC822 type 'Address'
or
The NotesName class in LotusScript can retrieve any part of a field of type 'RFC822 Text'